# В каких случаях итерации через Stream API использует многопоточность?

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-stream

Есть цепочка операций, которые должны выполняться строго в той последовательности, в которой лежат в коллекции. При такой записи возможно параллельное выполнение?

```
executables.stream().allMatch(Executable::execute);
```

Comment: ...вы только имейте в виду, что выполниться могут **не все**. Как только ответ станет однозначно известен, перебор прекратится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в цепочке не будет вызова `.parallel()` или сам стрим создан не с помощью `.parallelStream()`, то выполнение будет последовательным.